# Average gray value in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to take average gray value of an image?

Answer (score 7):

Your question is very vague, but if you mean that you want the arithmetic mean of a greyscale image:

```
img = imread('my_greyscale_image.bmp');
img_mean = mean(mean(img));
```

Note that the reason you need to apply `mean` twice is because the first time mean is applied to a matrix and it calculates the means of each column and returns these values as a vector. Applying mean again to this vector then gives you a single mean value for the whole matrix.

Comment: When doing statistics on the entire image, I find that it is better to stretch the image into a vector and then do the operation, i.e. img_mean = mean(img(:)); For the mean it does not matter, but for non-linear operations like the std and median it is important.

Comment: @Ghaul: good point - it would be more succinct (and probably more efficient) for linear operations such as mean too.

Comment: ok now what if i want to apply this average value on another image .mean if i want to multiply it with the image than....how to do it?????????

Comment: @chee: if you have a new question then you should probably post it as a separate question on SO. It sounds though like you just want to know how to multiply a matrix by a scalar value in Matlab ?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the manual (http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/rgb2gray.html):

```
I = imread('color_image.tif');
J = rgb2gray(I);
figure, imshow(I), figure, imshow(J);
```

Comment: The question is vague, but I think he wants to calculate the mean value of a greyscale image, not convert an RGB image to a greyscale image.

Comment: Gamma correction may also be needed to get a realistic average: http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma.html